# Intellij jvm doesnt show my console output

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

my problem is that when I write a code and run it, the console just doesnt show it.
I dont know anything about it and started new.
I installed a second time but still without success.
can you give me any tips to solve it, cause since two days I cant go on with my book.
thx very much.

Comment: Please provide the screenshot of the issue and the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the "Run" output, have you gone up to the "View" menu, then to "Tool Windows" then "Run"?  That is where most of the view window settings are in IntelliJ (and other JetBrains products)

Comment: above, "Process finished with exit code 0" has to stand my output. but no.

Comment: you'll want to edit your question to show your code then